# If text match any text in a child element, add class to this child?

Tags: jquery

How to check if a parent has the same text as per one of its childs and if so, add a class to this child?

html

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="class1" href="#">MY TEXT</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a class="class2" href="#">IPSUM</a></li>
       <li><a class="class2" href="#">MY TEXT</a></li>
       <li><a class="class2" href="#">LOREM</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(".class2").each(function() {
   if($(".class1").text() == $(".class2").text()) {
      $(this).addClass("current");
   }
});
```

Comment: You have tried something, didn't you?

Comment: what he's trying to tell you is: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: yeah got that, just the way...to be polite is also skill. Anyway, updating with what i tried.

Comment: Now please tell us if what you have tried works. If not, do you get an error? What *do* yo get?

Comment: FYI, your HTML is invalid (that inner `ul` is *not* a child of the `li`, it's just floating around as an invalid child of another `ul`). There is *no* parent-child relationship here. But bumbu's answer below is on target for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the addClass callback

```js
$('.class2').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).text() === $('.class1').text() && 'current';
});
```

```css
.current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a class="class1" href="#">MY TEXT</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="class2" href="#">IPSUM</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="class2" href="#">MY TEXT</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="class2" href="#">LOREM</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow, i didnt' know it had a callback. That's really nice to know. Thanks a lot

Comment: innerText isn't standard and doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: True, forgot about firefox. Changed it to the jQuery method

Answer (score 3):

Try this Out !!! I think this is what you wanted.

```
<ul class="parentUl">
 <li><a class="class1" href="#">MY TEXT</a>
   <ul class='childUl'>
      <li><a class="class2" href="#">IPSUM</a></li>
     <li><a class="class2" href="#">MY TEXT</a></li>
     <li><a class="class2" href="#">LOREM</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="class3" href="#">LOREM</a>
     <ul class='childUl'>
         <li><a class="class4" href="#">IPSUM</a></li>
         <li><a class="class4" href="#">MY TEXT</a></li>
         <li><a class="class4" href="#">LOREM</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



 $('ul.parentUl>li').each(function(i, item){ 
     $(item).find('ul>li').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('a').text() === $(item).children('a').text()){
           $(this).find('a').addClass('current');
       }
     });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ak58ph16/9/

Answer (score 2):

Update you jQuery to be like

```
$(".class2").each(function() {
   if($(".class1").text() == $(this).text()) {
      $(this).addClass("current");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(".class2").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === $(".class1").text();
}).addClass("current");
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g32r2xpn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this like that:

```
var myText = $(".class1")[0].text;
$(".class2").each(function(element){
     if (myText == this.text)
         $(this).addClass("yourClass");
});
```